# Clear Sonarqube Current Analysis

Tags: sonarqube

I want to clear Sonarqube project current code analysis and make the project blank. Is it possible? I know we can clear all the previous analysis, but I want to clear the current analysis of Sonarqube project.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean removing a "snapshot" of an analysis according to the most recent [SonarQube documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/managing-project-history/) you should be able to this.  Also if you have access to the database SonarQube is using then you could remove the analysis directly from there.  That option may introduce other issues though depending on how SonarQube handles it.

Comment: I have gone through the latest document link which you attached in a comment. But there also they mentioned `Note that the most recent snapshot (labeled " last snapshot") can never be deleted`, but as per my requirenment I want to make my project blank so How can I do that?

Comment: It's not supported, but if you have access to the database you can remove the project data from there.  Beware though, this is unsupported and may break SonarQube depending on how you remove the data.

Comment: I have one more issue. Sonarqube is showing old bugs in new bugs. why?

Comment: Do you have any link from where I can find steps to delete Sonarqube analysis?